# How is symmetry boundary condition related to reflection of a plane wave from a rigid flat surface?

Tags: waves, acoustics, boundary-conditions

My question is in in the context of "method of images" when applied to an incoming incident acoustic pr plane wave.

For a flat rigid surface in $XY$ system, the surface (positioned at $Y=0$) has the pressure boundary condition of $\frac{\partial p}{\partial n_s} = 0$ where $n_s$ is the surface normal. This B.C. was derived from linearized momentum equation of $\rho_0 \frac{\partial \overrightarrow{V}}{\partial t} = -\nabla p$ when $\overrightarrow{V}=0$ at $Y=0$.

An incoming incident plane wave on the flat surface is  $p_I(x,-y,t)$ on the flat surface. The incoming wave is angled and has components $\hat{e_x}$, $-\hat{e_y}$ and thus, the $-y$ sign.

If there is a point on the flat surface, let's say $S$, then by the pressure B.C., $p_S = p_I(x,-y,t)$. Going by the method of images approach, the flat surface can be considered as plane of symmetry and thus the pressure on $S$ is also $p_S = p_I'(x,y,t)$. The sign of $y$ is positive now, because the wave has now the components of $\hat{e_x}$ and $\hat{e_y}$ after taking symmetry. Mathematically, this would also mean that $p_I(x,-y,t) = p_I'(x,y,t)$.

Please let me know if I am wrong in my understanding up to this point.

My question is why should $p_I'(x,y,t)$ be considered as the reflected wave solution $p_R$? From a high-school physics perspective, this reasoning is related to the tracing of rays. However, what's the mathematical reasoning behind this?